# Mocking Apex Wire Adapter - "emit is not a function"

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am trying to set up a very simple test of a LWC apex wire adapter. This includes mocking the apex response with the contents of a JSON file as shown in the LWC docs.

```
...
import MyComponent from 'c/myComponent';
import myApexMethod from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.myApexMethod';

const mockResponse = require('./data/mockResponse.json');

describe('c-my-component', () => {
    
    afterEach(() => {
        while(document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
        // Prevent data saved on mocks from leaking between tests
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    describe('myApexMethod @wire data', () => {

        it('renders a table', () => {

            const element = createElement('c-my-component', {
                is: MyComponent
            });
            document.body.appendChild(element);

            // *** Failing here with "myApexMethod.emit is not a function" ***
            myApexMethod.emit(mockResponse);

            return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                // Assertions
            })
        });
    });
});
```

However, I am getting a `myApexMethod.emit is not a function` error and can't figure out what the issue is.

- I am definitely importing the method correctly.
- The `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest` library is installed.
- I have checked that my sfdx cli is up to date.

My understanding is that I don't have to register the wire adapter any more. What have I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I needed to upgrade the `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest` package version. This also meant upgrading the rest of the `devDependencies` in the `package.json` file, and the api version in the `sfdx-project.json` file.

Comment: I had the same problem. Could you explain a bit more specific how to upgrade the package?

Comment: @popo - I'm not aware of any nice and easy update via sfdx. I simply had a look at the `package.json` in the LWC recipes repo on GitHub (https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/package.json) and copied what I saw there. Then I deleted the `node_modules` folder in my project, and re-installed the dependencies using `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

The platform does not mock apex and apexContinuation methods, and test authors will need to keep implementing their mocks. Notice that when testing an apex method used with `@wire`, you should change your apex method mock to use `createApexTestWireAdapter`.

Try this

```
...

jest.mock(
  "@salesforce/apex/MyController.myApexMethod",
  () => {
    const { createApexTestWireAdapter } = require("@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest");
    return {
      default: createApexTestWireAdapter(jest.fn())
    };
  },
  { virtual: true }
);

...
//later
myApexMethod.emit(mockResponse);
```

For more info and examples check https://github.com/salesforce/wire-service-jest-util